# Null pointer on insert in SQLite release mode

Tags: android

I have published my app to PlayStore, in debug all was going well, in the new version i've added two new tables, the insert method and other stuff and changed the db version.

The issue is that once i've downloaded the PlayStore version of the APP the app suddenly crashed with the following error:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.database.DataBaseHandler.insertMC (DataBaseHandler.java:59)
it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.TastiActivity$1.onCompleted (TastiActivity.java:32)
it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.TastiActivity$1.onCompleted (TastiActivity.java:2)
com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked (SimpleFuture.java:10)
com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete (SimpleFuture.java:22)
```

Logcat:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at y5.a.N(:216)
        at it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.TastiActivity.Q(:464)
        at it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.TastiActivity.o(Unknown Source:0)
        at v5.r0.a(Unknown Source:4)
        at b5.h.p(:107)
        at b5.h.v(:141)
        at b5.h.w(:128)
        at m5.l$a.run(:246)
        at z4.g$l.run(:60)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

insertMC is one of new methods to insert the data in the new created tables, so i think that in release version of the app the new tables were not created so that's the reason why the app crash in that point.

The issue is that even after uninstalling and installing the app again (which should forced the onCreate of DBHandler) the issue still persists...

Here is the method:

```
   public void insertMC(Menu menu) {
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues valuesMenu = new ContentValues();

        valuesMenu.put("DESCRIPTION", menu.desc);
        valuesMenu.put("OPZIONALE", menu.opzionale);
        valuesMenu.put("LIMITE", menu.limite);
        valuesMenu.put("PLU", menu.plu);

        long id = database.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_MC, null, valuesMenu, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

        for (Menu.Prodotti prodotto :
                menu.prodotti) {
            ContentValues valuesProdotto = new ContentValues();

            valuesProdotto.put("DESCRIPTION", prodotto.desc);
            valuesProdotto.put("CODICE", prodotto.codice);
            valuesProdotto.put("PREZZO", prodotto.prezzo);
            valuesProdotto.put("QTA", prodotto.qta);
            valuesProdotto.put("MENU", id);
            valuesProdotto.put("JUMP", prodotto.jump);
            database.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_MC_PRODOTTI, null, valuesProdotto, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        }
    }
```

What should be the issue? if that's DB table creation problem, how can i force it in release? Else how can i run a debug of a release version of the app?

release attributes:

```
release {
    debuggable true
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

My proguard:

```
-keep class org.sqlite.** { *; }
-keep class org.sqlite.database.** { *; }
-keep class it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.models.Menu
```

Comment: If in your build.gradle minifyEnabled is set to true then try to add `-keep class org.sqlite.** { *; }` and `-keep class org.sqlite.database.** { *; }` add these lines in proguard-rules.pro

Comment: @UsamaAltaf just tried to add it but i still get the same issue..

Comment: you should add both lines in proguard-rules.pro file you can find this file under Gradle scripts section where your build.gradle is located also

Comment: You should also add `Menu` to -keep in proguard.

Comment: https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android/blob/master/sqlite-android/proguard-rules.pro go this link and copy the rules from here and paste it

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki added menù but still crashing, by setting minify to false it's working so it's definitly an issue with the minify..

Comment: https://proguard-rules.blogspot.com/2017/07/android-dbtools-proguard-rules.html

Comment: solved it. thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @UsamaAltaf i got that the issue was with the minifyEnabled property, so by investigating i've ended up that the issue was the minified model class `Menu`

The solution was to add it to proguard, so to make it work i've added this lines to proguard:

```
-keep class it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.models.Menu
-keepclassmembers class it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.models.Menu { *; }
```

It wasn't necessary to add `-keep` on `sqlite` class.